# Primefaces dynamic table property

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How can i reach the subClass property of a variable. As you can see Primefaces example I can reach properties like Car.color, Car.shape but what I want to get is "Car.PriceInformations.Price". I tried car[column.property][column.subproperty] but it didnt worked. Must I use subtable or is there any better solution?

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" filteredValue="#{tableBean.filteredCars}">                      
    <p:columns value="#{tableBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex"   
                sortBy="#{car[column.property]}" filterBy="#{car[column.property]}">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            #{column.header}  
        </f:facet>  

        #{car[column.property]}  
    </p:columns>  

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: is `Car.PriceInformations` a collection? and do you want to access one of the item in the collection?

Comment: Try to access the same property in java class does it accessible as your editor might shows errors/suggestion for this expression

Comment: @erencan it is not a collection. just an object

Comment: @Jitesh It is accessible. There is no problem with access. When I try "car["priceInformations"]["price"]", it shows priceInformation's toString method in cell.

Comment: I guess this is what you looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722255/no-access-to-nested-property-in-managed-bean-within-pcolumns

Comment: @TurgutDsfadfa have you tried to access by using `#{Car.PriceInformations.Price}` ?

Comment: @erencan As I said I have dynamic columns.

Comment: @MukulGoel I have SpringBeanFacesELResolver as resolver. I extended it  as example shows but now my spring controllers are not initializing. I think this line returns null '    if (property == null || base == null || base instanceof ResourceBundle || base instanceof Map || base instanceof Collection) {
            return null;
        }'

Comment: @TurgutDsfadfa sorry bro, I just pulled that link out. If you have any questions, post that on the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify [this BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722474/892994) according to your needs.

Basically you can extend `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` as you use it for EL resolver. However, EL resolver is looking for Spring Bean inside Spring Context. [Source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/2.5/spring-2.5-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java?format=ok) give very good understanding what SpringBenFacesELResolver do.

Secondly you need `javax.el.BeanELResolver` to access managed bean values as descriped in BalusC answer. I use Java Reflections for this purpose. `javax.el.BeanELResolver` can be loaded inside `SpringBeanFacesELResolver` dynamicly at run tim then invoke `SpringBeanFacesELResolver#getValue` for nested properties just like in the referenced answer.

Here is the code:

```
public class ExtendedSpringELResolver extends SpringBeanFacesELResolver {

@Override
public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property)
{
    if (property == null || base == null || base instanceof ResourceBundle || base instanceof Map || base instanceof Collection) {
        return null;
    }

    String propertyString = property.toString();

    if (propertyString.contains(".")) {
        Object value = base;
        Class []params=  new Class[]{ELContext.class,Object.class,Object.class};
        for (String propertyPart : propertyString.split("\\.")) {

            Class aClass = BeanELResolver.class;

            try {
                Method getValueMethod = aClass.getDeclaredMethod("getValue",params );
                value = getValueMethod.invoke(aClass.newInstance(), context, value, propertyPart);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return value;
    }
    else {
        return super.getValue(context, base, property);
    }

}
```

}

**P.S.** I tried the code with the example in [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf). I change `String color` to `Color color` where `Color` is a user defined class for my case which has only a String proporty. I access the values by adding `color.color` to columns list.

```
private String columnTemplate = "model manufacturer year color.color";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only collection in your table bean is `TableBean#carsSmall`, then don't use `<p:columns>` in your JSF page.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}>
   <p:column headerText="Car brand">
      <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer.name}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Color">
      <h:outputText value="#{car.color.name}" />
      <h:outputText value="#{car.color.code}" />
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And don't forget to create proper getters and setters in your `TableBean`, `Manufacturer` and `Color` classes (as your classes will have different names).

Comment: I have other collections so I need to use <p:columns>.

Comment: Ok, try `#{car[colIndex].property}`, because you have to use the expression from `colIndexVar property to access the field. If this is not the solution provide your bean code, please. It is necessary to know what types your bean fields are, otherwise this is just guessing.